# Codeigniter returning custom id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a code in  my model that will insert a new data and returns the inserted ID, but it doesn't return the correct ID instead it returns "0" value

```
function insert_request($data){
  $this->db->insert('radiology_request', $data);
  $request_id = $this->db->insert_id();
  return $request_id;
}
```

My primary key is custom auto-increment. It has a format like "REQ-00001". How do I return the last inserted ID ?

Comment: The `$this->db->insert_id();` only function with the id autoincrement and called id

Comment: you using codeigniter 2 ? or codeigniter 3 ?

Comment: codeigniter 3 @AniruddhaChakraborty

Comment: How did you solve it? You you can answer your own question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

I've solved it by creating another query to select the last row.

```
function insert_request($data){
  $this->db->insert('radiology_request', $data);
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('radiology_request');
  $this->db->order_by("request_id", "desc");
  $this->db->limit(1);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->row();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code with more generic feeling.

```
function insert_request($tablename,$data_arr){
         $ret = 0;        
        try {    
            $this->db->insert($tablename, $data_arr);
            $ret = $this->db->insert_id() + 0; 
            return $ret;
        } catch (Exception $err) {
            return $err->getMessage();
        }
```

Comment: it doesn't work either, but I already solved it. Thanks anyway!